# Puzzle with pictures in vertical pairs

Tags: visual

I am struggling to solve this picture. It's toilet paper roll over then a baby chick and then a 23 with a crown on it. The second part is toilet paper roll under, an egg and then the Michael Jordan sign

[image: image described above]

Comment: I can definitely see how someone might think it was a puzzle, but SQLnoob's answer makes sense to me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not really a puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it's not a riddle, it's just a picture of three common topics of debate. The first is, "Should the toilet paper go over or under?" The second is, "Which came first, the chicken or the egg?" And the third is, "Who is the better basketball player, Lebron James or Michael Jordan?"

I'm assuming it's just a humorous sign meant to start some bar conversations.

Comment: Lebron James is the number 6 since 2021. So this is a outdated puzzle.